# File Buffer doesn't flush on a Network Drive

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, network-programming

I have written a C++ program to write to a file on a network drive path mapped to "O:\Temp\test.csv".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream* fptr = new std::ofstream("O:\\Temp\\test.csv");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        (*fptr) << i << ":"
            << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
            << "\n";
        fptr->flush();
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    fptr->close();
    delete fptr;

}
```

On the network drive, I have opened the file in Notepad++. However, after first few lines are updated in the network file, the network file stops getting updated. The network file is updated once the `fstream` is closed at the end of the program.

To prove my hypothesis that it is a network file issue, when I write to a local file (by changing the path to `"test.csv"` string), each line is updated as it is written to the stream.

I am wondering if it is possible to make sure that the file is written to a network path as soon as we write to the stream in our program? I suspect it may be an issue with the receive network buffer which is not being flushed.

**Problem Context**
I am writing 100's of files being updated every 10 or 15 seconds. Closing and then reopening the stream in append mode seems to work, but it seems it is a costly operation.

Comment: Since this appears to be going over SMB, you may be able to tune the `RemoteFileDirtyPageThreshold`, which controls how much it'll allow to be written before flushing data to disk. Unfortunately, you can apparently only set it on a server-wide basis, and reducing it can hurt performance quite a bit. Given the requirement, it may be easier to set up a small file transfer service of your own that flushes data to disk immediately upon receipt (without affecting other file sharing).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes it is making sense. With heavy heart, I am inclined to close the stream after writing it and reopening it in `std::ios::app` mode. It seems to do the trick, but I'm not sure how costly operation it is. The problem is that I'm crunching a lot of data and writing 100's of files being updated every 10 seconds. So, I'm worried if closing and reopening file streams is a neat way to go.